# Scala with Spray routing - halting execution and returning after a HttpResponse?

Tags: scala, spray

I'm having an issue with Spray Routing in my current Scala project - it appears that after executing a HttpResponse clause like follows;

```
complete(HttpResponse(500, HttpEntity("There was an error in handling your request.")))
```

the script appears to continue on down the 'happy' path until it reaches the final complete(HttpResponse) statement.

In the above example, the script throws back the above error if an unsupported/restricted parameter type is used. However, the script then continues on, and tries to carry out the request anyway.

One 'workaround' I attempted on this was setting;

```
var validRequest = true
```

which then gets flipped to false if the above HttpResponse is triggered. However, wrapping the 'happy path' around this conditional results in an error as follows;

```
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: spray.routing.directives.OnCompleteFutureMagnet[?]
```

I imagine this is occurring as the 'happy path' enters into a promise/future as it needs to carry out some I/O on mongo. As such, it leaves the script thinking there's a possibility of never exiting this method.

One thought I've had is to wrap the entire method inside a promise/future - but I'm unsure on if this is feasible/possible within Scala.

Could someone please point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? Perhaps a single route which reproduces your problem.